# Is there any way or any snippet for WordPress to minimize render size of stylesheet specified in tag 'style amp-custom'?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I'm using wordpress and AMP for my mobile things. But the amp page gives me errors like this "Author stylesheet specified in tag 'style amp-custom' exceeds limit of 50000 bytes", and i did check the style in tag 'style amp-costum' and it is exceeds limit of 50K that AMP set for default. Is there any way to make the stylesheet be under 50K rendered?

Comment: remove all the unwanted styles

Comment: @charankumar but i can't just remove the unused styles since all of the styles are coming from the template, i didn't put any custom style into it..